# Is it possible to use interface functions as types?

Tags: solidity, data-types, function

I would like to use a function defined in an interface as a [function type](https://twitter.com/PaulRBerg/status/1609917508223475712), like this:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.17;

interface Foo {
    function myFunction() external;
}

contract Contract {
    function myOtherFunction(Foo.myFunction func) external;
}
```

The code above does not compile, though. Is there any way to use interface functions as types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked the same question in the [Solidity Matrix server](https://app.element.io/#/room/#ethereum_solidity:gitter.im), and a Solidity language developer has replied by saying that this is not currently possible.

The reason being that there's no runtime type information or checking.

> currently interface functions don't have types beyond their signature, i.e. the type of `Foo.myFunction` is just `function () external` and semantically it's just an address plus a selector without any additional type information.